# How to specify the Cardano address for BlockFrost Transaction Endpoint?

Tags: api, blockfrost, python, transaction-history

Hi im trying to call this [https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/~1addresses~1{address}~1transactions/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/%7E1addresses%7E1%7Baddress%7D%7E1transactions/get) from some code I wrote (images attached below) and get a None or Empty value returned.

I am using the receiving address from my wallet and am wondering if I'm using the wrong address? how should I find the right one?

Below is the output of some print statements I wrote:

endpoint:

addresses/addr1q8mw47vt7kf69ze5x92luhrxvk0p2vpd0emvhlg704u7cttdrr3j8j5k5yacga4ckv6lnx4p0la57q7nf24eszqk0r2q59elsd/transactions

Full Request:

https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/addresses/addr1q8mw47vt7kf69ze5x92luhrxvk0p2vpd0emvhlg704u7cttdrr3j8j5k5yacga4ckv6lnx4p0la57q7nf24eszqk0r2q59elsd/transactions

Returned Value: None

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your question I will assume you are trying to get the transaction history of your wallet? The endpoint you are using requires an address previously associated with a transaction, and an unused receiving address won't return anything.

Your wallet consists of multiple UTxOs across multiple addresses, and that information is persisted locally by the wallet software so it's easy to obtain details like the transaction history. However in the context of statelessly querying Blockfrost you will have to retrieve all these addresses using the [Account associated addresses
endpoint](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Accounts/paths/%7E1accounts%7E1%7Bstake_address%7D%7E1addresses/get) and then query the transactions per address. It might be a little easier using the [Koios API because the resource takes an array of addresses](https://api.koios.rest/#post-/address_txs) but there is no easy way to achieve what you want at the moment.